# Find two rows of a column belongs to same row of another column

Tags: sql-server

I have a table where I need to find list of subjects that have students from same department without using a subquery or Join

I tried to do the having count of department but it does not provide the output.

```
SELECT A.Subject,
       B.StudentID,
       B.DEPTID 
FROM AUTHOR A , ACADEMIC B 
WHERE A.StudentID = B.StudentID
GROUP BY B.DEPT,
         A.Subject,
         B.StudentID
```

Gives me the table output

```
Subject StudentID   DEPT
1       100         100
1       101         100
2       102         100
3       103         100
3       104         100
```

I expect the output to give me the subject that has studentID from same department without using subquery or JOIN.

Comment: There are many problems with your question. One - we do not know the columns of your tables - you should help us out here and present them, preferably with their data too. Two - by "not using join", do you mean you need the old syntax for some reason? Keep in mind that even your query *does* make a join behind the scenes. You will find everywhere that using the old syntax is bad practice and everyone recommends writing `JOIN` instead.

Comment: Even syntax like `SELECT * FROM Table1 T1, Table2 T2 WHERE T1.ID = T2.fID;` is still a `JOIN` @GeorgeMenoutis it's just using the ANSI-89 JOIN syntax (which like you said, has been outdated since the ANSI-92 syntax was introduced 27 years ago, so there's no reason to really use it anymore, apart from perhaps when doing a bunch of Cross Joins). If the OP doesn't want to use a Join this task is actually impossible, as even within an `EXISTS` a Join is performed.

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)